# How to update UI of a view from another view [ SwiftUI Question]

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am new to Swift & iOS dev in general.

I am building an app in SwiftUI. Assume there are 2 separate views in different files: MainView() & Results() and TabBar()(ignore the naming, this is just an example)(those 2 views are ON 2 SEPARATE TABS)

My goal is to press on that button FROM ResultsView() and change the textValue property of MainView() to something else & then display the change ON the MainView(). How can I do that? P.S Please ignore alignment & etc. I am new to StackOverflow

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @State var textValue: String = "Old Text"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(textValue)
    }
    
}

struct TabBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            MainView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Main", systemImage: "circle.dashed.inset.filled")
                }
            ResultsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Results", systemImage: "person.2.crop.square.stack.fill")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ResultsView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            // HOW TO UPDATE MainView.textValue?
        } label: {
            Text("Update")
        }
    }
}
```

- ContentView() just has TabBar() in body

Basically, my question is how do we change UI of certain view from another view? Without NavigationLink

Might sound like a rookie question, but any reply will be so appreciated!

Comment: Look into using the `@State` and `@Binding` property wrappers for your property, there should be plenty of articles and tutorials available

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your suggestion, but I already looked into it and I am still not able to do it. I am using tab bar navigation, so I am really lost here

Comment: Is there any way I can send you a code to look at? It is really simple, just 2 views in 2 separate tabs with 1-2 elements inside. I have been looking for solution and this would help SO MUCH

Comment: Rather than sending code to someone privately, it's probably best to update your question with a [mre] of what you've tried -- that way, anyone can answer and later, other users can try to learn from the same information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing the `textValue` from MainView to DetailView through a `@Binding`.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State private var text: String = "Original"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text(text)
                NavigationLink("Detail", destination: DetailView(text: $text))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Change Text") {
            text = "New Text"
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend you read [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-binding-property-wrapper) about bindings as it explains how to change a view from elsewhere.

**Edit:**
Because you mentioned, that both views are in a `TabBar`, here should be a working example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = "Original Text"
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            MainView(text: $text)
                .tabItem { ... }
            DetailView(text: $text)
                .tabItem { ... }
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        Button("Change Text") {
            text = "New Text"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cameron, thank you so much! I appreciate your reply from bottom of heart. This is correct, but this is not applicable in my case, because in my case those 2 views are not connected through NavLink. Those 2 views are on separate tabs(with tab bar). I have tried creating object of MainView() and accessing the textValue property from DetailView()(let mainVC = MainView(), mainVC.username = "New Text", but it didn't work as well

Comment: Store the `@State` in the parent of the tab bar and pass it down to the child views via `@Binding`.

Comment: You can then put the @State in the View that contains the TabBar and let the MainView and DetailView have a Binding

Comment: Thank you @jnpdx! I will definitely give it a try now. This is my first month learning Swift & programming in general, so I am not really sure how to do that exactly, but I will look into it. If you share an exact code, that would be beyond amazing, but in any case I appreciate you taking the time to help out

Comment: Thank you Cameron! You guys are the best, this gives me some hope. If possible, please show me how it is done, but anyways thank you so much

Comment: @JohnWaywhick someone can probably show you the exact code, but first, you should post the code that *you tried* -- that way, someone can pinpoint what went awry. Can you edit your original question with your real code rather than just a description of the issue?

Comment: @jnpdx I certainly can, sorry for not doing that in the first place. Pretty new to StackOverflow & programming in general. Can you give me 10-15 mins?

Comment: @jnpdx just updated question with code. Any insight will be much appreciated!

Comment: @JohnWaywhick I already updated my answer

Comment: @Cameron You are literally a legend! Thank you so so much, literally spent so much time looking for that solution. Massive thanks, you can't imagine how happy I am right now lol!